# enter a specific object value

Tags: zend-framework2

i'm using zendframwork 2 , i implement the album exemple in the official documentation 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/user-guide/overview.html#the-tutorial-application  (so in my model folder i have Album.php and AlbumTable.php) and all works fine , i just want to make a small modification :

i want to have acces to the third element in album . in the index.phtml view (originally i have this code )

```
<?php foreach ($albums as $album) : ?>

<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($album->title);?>
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($album->artist);?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

i tried things like

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($album->title[3]);?>
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($album[3]->title);?>

but i always get this error 
( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Auth\Model\Album as array in   C:\wamp\www\zf2-album\module\Auth\view\auth\auth\index.phtml on line 14
```

any help please ?
thanks every one

Answer (score 0):

Do you need ONLY the third one? Then write your Query to be more efficient ;) For all other cases, since you are working with a [`Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/library/Zend/Db/ResultSet), which uses [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/de/class.iterator.php) you have different options.

The first one would be to still iterate through the fieldset like

```
while ($albums->key() != 3) {
    $albums->next();
}
$album = $albums->current();
```

The alternative would be to simply convert the `ResultSet` into an [`array`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/ResultSet/AbstractResultSet.php#L254)

```
$myAlbums = $albums->toArray();
$album    = $myAlbums[3];
```

Depending on how big your `ResultSet` is and how many entries you really need, either Solution may be faster for you. Guess you have to test that one ;)

Comment: thanks for your help , i used the first methode and the application still loading with no result(it seems that zf2 is blocked) , i opt more for the second solution but i get this error                This result is a forward only result set, calling rewind() after moving forward is not supported

Comment: Yep, you can only go forward. Provide your actual code if there's new problems ;)